# html is pass using jquery ajax but pdf is not generating in mpdf for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, mpdf

I want to create a PDF in codeigniter using `mPDF`. My html is passed to the controller using jQuery AJAX. Data is coming to the `$html` But it is not working. It works fine when html is hard coded. Can any one help me please?

```
public function pdf($paper='A4')
{
    $html = '';
    $html = $this->input->POST('content');
    $this->load->library('mpdf54/mpdf');
    $CI->mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8',$paper);
    $mpdf->debug = true;

    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->mpdf->Output(); 
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: Is the content of `$html` good if you output it? (Using `echo` or  `print_r`)

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing all the POST vars by using

```
$html = $this->input->POST();
```

then echo those out to yourself before moving farther to be sure they are getting set.

```
public function pdf($paper='A4')
{
    print_r($this->input->POST());
    return;
}
```

This of course is only for testing but might help you to see why your $html var isn't getting set. Try that out and give us the results.